# AngularJS shows undefined function for controller

Tags: angularjs

I have just created a simple app. Route for `main controller` is working but not for another one.
This is the part of the code of route file

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
    controller: 'MainController',
    controllerAs: 'main'
  })
  .when('/signatures', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/signature/signature.html',
    controller: 'SignatureController',
    controllerAs: 'signature',
    resolve: {
      signatureLists: function(SignatureService){
        return SignatureService.getSignatures();
      }
    }
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

and below is the controller

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('demoapp')
    .controller('SignatureController', SignatureController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function SignatureController(signatureLists) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.signatures = signatureLists;
  }
})
```

I have defined the module in another file:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('demoapp', ['ngRoute', 'toastr']);

})();
```

when I try to visit `/signatures` page, I get this error:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'SignatureController' is not a function, got undefined

Maybe its just a silly error due to a typo or something else but still I can't figure it out

Comment: You forgot to self invoke the controller closure..do a () at the end

Comment: check whether you added that script in your html `<script src= " ...." >`

Comment: As you have defined both your module and controller in different files, you will have include both .js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to self invoke the controller closure..do a () at the end

```
(function() {
 'use strict';

 angular
 .module('demoapp')
 .controller('SignatureController', SignatureController);

 /** @ngInject */
 function SignatureController(signatureLists) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.signatures = signatureLists;
 }
})()
```

Comment: I knew this would be something like this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @sajan - no probs, I have done this mistake 100 times :)